# change dial image of Analog CLock widget Android

Tags: android, widget, clock

I am creating a home screen widget for android (learning purpose) and using AnalogClock widget, I want to change the dial and hands of that widget once user click at a button on screen.

Any ideas on how can I achieve it (it's kind of changing themes of the clock)?

Answer (score 1):

you can change them pretty easily..

just follow this code

```
<AnalogClock
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:dial="@drawable/clockface"
    android:hand_minute="@drawable/minuteImage"
    android:hand_hour="@drawable/hourImage"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't use custom widget on AppWidget design.
You can refer to my blogpost to see why.
http://yenliangl.blogspot.tw/2010/06/appwidget-design-can-i-use-my-own.html

Comment: thank you I used so other trick used an imageview and now I change image src for it but thanks :)